# How to set default params in can.Control.route

Tags: javascript, routes, canjs, canjs-routing

When using the can.Control.route documented [here](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Control.route.html), I can not manage to set default parameters values as it is possible when using the classical declarative way as follow :

```
can.route("content/:type", {type: "videos" });
```

Is there a way to set the default value of a router parameter when using the route Control ?

Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to define the route in your control and then set the default value as described above:

```
can.Control.extend({
  'content/:type route': function() {
    //
  }
});

can.route("content/:type", { type: "videos" });
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for feedback. It was not really what I was searching for. If I do that way, it makes me write the same piece of code twice. I think I'll switch back to the declarative way.

Comment: Yes it does but there isn't really a way to do anything more but declare the route as a string in the Control route plugin. Although content/ should call the same route with an empty type, so you could just use `data.type || 'video'` in the handler.